# What's the meaning of Visiting Researcher / Ass. Professor?

Tags: united-states, terminology, canada, assistant-professor, visiting

I want to know how actually (and on the basis of what) visiting researcher (for PhD students) or visiting Ass. Professor (for lecturers) opportunities are offered worldwide (especially for USA/Canada) ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the European countries I've seen the answer would be similar:

**Visiting researcher** is not really a type of (funded) position, but a status. PhD students might do a research visit as part of their doctoral studies while still being paid by their home institution, sometimes supported by a travel grant to cover travel and housing costs. There are also post-doc grants providing 1- or 2-year funding that are implemented by having the involved institution host the postdoc as a visiting researcher. Finally, a professor on a sabbatical might visit another institution for a couple of months and in the course of that take on the visiting researcher status.

**Fixed-term lecturer or teacher** positions are created by the department as a regular type of position  (the term "visiting assistant professor" is usually not used). They usually have to be publicly announced and advertised, although the effort for advertisement is usually smaller than for a tenure-track or tenured position.

Comment: OK, But for the Fixed-term lecturer what are the requirements in general in Canada ?

Comment: @Sam If it's anything like in Europe, you will need a PhD or be close to finishing one, and have expertise aligned with the acute teaching needs of the department.

Comment: Does this mean a PhD degree and some teaching experience ? or that the PHD topic should be right in the teaching topic ? also 'close to finishing one' means it's OK to start before the thesis defense ?

Comment: @Sam They might need someone to teach the course on databases, or hexapoda. Then the call would mention that and you should point out your relevant experiences in the application.

Comment: @Sam Yes, starting before the defense would probably be OK, depending on the country (I know one country in Europe where it might be a problem, but that seems to be the minority). When you apply for a specific call, the call will mention this, or you can also contact their contact person.

Comment: Alright and typically what is the proposed duration of the contract (for the fixed-term lecturer) for a fresh grad ?

Comment: @Sam The duration of the position will usually not depend on the person, but be announced as part of the call. One or two years would be a typical duration.

Comment: Very clear ! thanks !